# Backup Mac and IOS devices locally

Tags: iphone, ipad, macbook-pro, backup

I have a friend who lives where there isn't very fast Internet connectivity. He has a Mac Book, an iPad, and some iPhones. He has a decent WiFi hotspot. He wants to back up everything, possibly to a disk drive also connected to his home router - either WiFi or wired. He would also like to be able to restore things, should the need arise. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Connect the device to iTunes (over Wi-Fi or USB), then select to backup the device. This will backup the contents of the device to ~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup/ which can be copied to an external drive. To restore from backup, copy the folder back and restore from this backup.

Answer (score 0):

With so many devices to back up you should consider the

[AirPort Time Capsule](https://www.apple.com/airport-time-capsule/).

With AirPort Time Capsule, you get a superfast Wi‑Fi base station and an easy-to-use backup device all in one.

And backing up your data couldn’t be simpler. Just set it up once and AirPort Time Capsule does the rest.

- The iPhone and iPad back up to iTunes on your Mac.
- Then, when your Mac backs up to the Time Capsule, the iOS backups are copied over as well.
- The iPhone and iPad cannot backup directly to the Time Capsule.

See this [Apple Support document](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4199) for more details on backups.

Comment: OP wants to back up locally, so iCloud is not an option